# Determine why PI didn't connect to a WiFi

Tags: wifi, headless, logfiles

I setup my Pi to connect to wifi by entering login details for two WiFi networks in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I managed to get this to work with one wifi, but now I'm somewhere else and the Pi can not be found in the second network that I entered.

This is my `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=CZ
# this one works
network={
    ssid="MY_HOME_WIFI"
    psk="ABCDEFG"
}
#this one does not work
network={
    ssid="MY_SECOND_WIFI"
    psk="123456"
}
```

One thing I noticed is that the first wifi used tabs and the second spaces to indent the config params.

Here is some grep result for wpa_supplicant in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr 12 08:42:29 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[187]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Apr 12 08:42:31 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[275]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Apr 12 08:42:35 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[293]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Apr 12 08:42:35 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[293]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
```

The network uses WPA2 (personal) and AES encryption.

I shut the Pi down now. I have no monitor, so I can only access a dead system. Is there any log I could find on Pi's SD card to determine what is wrong and why doesn't it connect?

Comment: plenty of logs in `/var/log`

Comment: @JaromandaX There's plenty for sure, but I didn't find anything that would identify a problem.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi is managed by **wpa_supplicant** and it logs to the default logging system. This is done by the `systemd-journald.service`. On a running system you will find logged messages with `journalctl` but on a dead system you cannot simply read the journal because it's a database and not readable in clear text. Fortunately messages are also logged to the old `/var/log/syslog` in parallel. So you can look at this file if you find some messages why *wpa_supplicant* hasn't connected. Look at it with `grep "dhcpcd.*wlan0" /var/log/syslog`. You may also have a look at the other log files in `/var/log/`.

Comment: I found nothing that would help me in the log.

Comment: @TomášZato What do you find with `grep 'dhcpcd.*wlan0' /var/log/syslog`?